# What is the background music of this part of Medieval Shorts 3 (probably from RPG Maker)?

Tags: game-music-identification, medieval-shorts-3

I have been struggling to find the background music of the scene with the angels in [Medieval Shorts 3](https://www.kongregate.com/games/vasantj/medieval-shorts-3). The relevant scene can be seen in [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/a6M403pHhoQ?t=991). **I am interested in the music that plays between minutes 16:30 and 17:00 in that video**.

Most of the music in that series of games comes from RPG Maker MV, and can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3pCLtTUMFk). However, I have not been able to find this particular track.

Maybe someone recognizes this track and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Well, if you have a save at the right point, then looking at the Developer Tools console can tell you what suffix to append to "https://game275397.konggames.com/gamez/0027/5397/live/" to get the music you're hearing. I can't see a way to extract all the game files just yet.
...
Maybe download it with Chrome via: https://www.reddit.com/r/incremental_games/comments/4wgkq0/is_there_any_way_to_download_a_game_from/